# Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Field1__c

Tags: apex, visualforce

VF :

```
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-space">
     <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-12"> 
       <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap margin-top-right">
         <div class="slds-card">
          <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">      
              <div class="slds-media__body">
                   <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-truncate">DETAILS</h2>
              </div>
             </div>
          <div class="slds-no-flex">
              <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-border-filled">
              <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon">
                  <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
              </svg>        
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-card__body">
           <apex:outputPanel id="details">
                <apex:dataTable value="{!CaseDetails}" var="account" id="theTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">

 <apex:facet name="caption">table caption</apex:facet>
   <apex:facet name="header">table header</apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="footer">table footer</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
  <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
<apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!CaseDetails.Field1__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column>
            <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
            <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!CaseDetails.Field2__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
           </apex:dataTable>
          </apex:outputPanel>
         </div>
        </div>                                      
       </div>
      </div>
```

Controller :

```
public List<Case> getCaseDetails()

{
    List<Case> cd = new List<Case>();

    if(cd == null) cd = [SELECT Field1 ,Field2  FROM Case WHERE Agency__c =:currentRecordId limit 1 ];

    return cd;
}
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Updated code :

```
  <apex:dataTable value="{!CaseDetails}" var="cs" id="theTable" 
                                         rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">
<apex:facet name="caption">table caption</apex:facet>
<apex:facet name="header">table header</apex:facet>
<apex:facet name="footer">table footer</apex:facet>
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cs.Field1__c}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!cs.Field2__c}"/>
</apex:column>
```

Error again :Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Field1__c'

Comment: SFDCRookie.. Can you please close this question as well..

Comment: SFDCRookie.. pls this is not a good practice to leave a question open

Answer (score 1):

You need to use var value ie. `account` instad of `CaseDetails` inside dataTable

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!CaseDetails}" var="account" id="theTable" 
                                             rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">
    <apex:facet name="caption">table caption</apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="header">table header</apex:facet>
    <apex:facet name="footer">table footer</apex:facet>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!account.Field1__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="footer">column footer</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!account.Field2__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: I made the changes , but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: @SFDCRookie are you getting same error? is there any other table?

Comment: There are no other table . Anything else needs to be done in the controller ? Any specific declarations?

Comment: @SFDCRookie can you please add your updated code in question? and also the error

Comment: @Ratan- Updated . Please let me know if there is anything wrong in the logic/syntax.

Answer (score 0):

May not address original post, but I was getting this because I had a controller extension Apex Class that returned a list of records, and I called the var in my pageBlockTable the same name as the recordSetVar. recordSetVar only goes one level deep (fields directly on the object) and I was referencing parent fields through __r. notation.

VF Page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="My_Object__c" recordSetVar="myObj" extensions="MyObjectExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.My_Object__c.labelPlural}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myObjList}" var="myObj">
            <apex:column headerValue="Object Manager" value="{!myObj.Manager__r.Name}"/>
```

Apex code:

```
public with sharing class MyObjectExtension {
public List<My_Object__c> myObjList {get; set;}

public MyObjectExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrlr) {
    this.myObjList = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Manager__c, Manager__r.Name
        FROM My_Object__c
        ORDER BY Manager__r.Name
    ];
```

**FIX**: change either recordSetVar on page or var on table